# Run a library Module from Main Module in Marklogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

**Updated Code**

My library Module is like this

```
   module namespace test="http://try.marklogic.com/test";
declare function test:median(
  $map as map:map*
) as node()*
{
cts:search(fn:doc(),
  cts:and-query((
  cts:element-word-query(
      xs:QName("College"),map:get($map,"College")),
  cts:element-word-query(
      xs:QName("Year"),map:get($map,"Year")),
   cts:element-word-query(
      xs:QName("Dep"),map:get($map,"Dep")),
   cts:element-word-query(
      xs:QName("Grade"),map:get($map,"Grade")),
   cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("Date"), ">",
      map:get($map,"StartDate")),
   cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("Date"), "<",
      map:get($map,"EndDate")))))
};
```

My Main Module is like this

```
import module namespace test = "http://try.marklogic.com/test" at "/lib1.xqy";

let $map := map:map()
let $College := "UCLA"
let $Year := "2000"
let $StartDate := xs:date("2017-01-06")
let $EndDate := xs:date("2018-01-06")
let $Dep := "CSE"
let $Grade := "A"
let $put := ( map:put($map, "College",$College),
            map:put($map, "Year",$Year),
            map:put($map, "Date",$StartDate),
            map:put($map, "Date",$EndDate),
            map:put($map, "Dep",$Dep),
            map:put($map, "Grade",$Grade) )
return test:median($map)
```

How can i pass the parameters separately rather than specifying in the main module ?

Comment: You are passing in arguments as map:map. Is that deliberate? If you pass in a map:map, you need to get map entries using for instance map:get($map, 'College'). Alternatively, you could also declare all arguments, and pass them through separately..

Comment: By the way, your range-queries on JoiningDate probably won't return results as they are likely mutually exclusive. One date can't both be smaller and bigger than some value..

Comment: Thanks@grtjn As you suggested i modified the code and i had worked fine. As you said `you could also declare all arguments, and pass them through separately.` How can i do that ?

Comment: `declare function test:median($College, $year, ...)`, and then you invoke it with `test:median($College, $year, ...)`...

Comment: Means you are saying instead of map , will use them separately like `$College`,`$Year,...`  right ?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the "`as cts:search`" line 4 in your library.

If you need to define a return type (you dont need to from the language perspective) then use the return type your actually returning.
That would be the *results* of `cts:search()`,  "`as node()*`"

see: https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search